# Python splitting string to pieces then adjusting their results

Tags: python, regex, string, split, strip

I am trying to make the code below work as intended. I got it to work to accept numbers, - sign for negative numbers and a dot sign for percision. But the code still allows for multiple - and . signs. And it doesn't check if it starts or ends with them.

I want to only get numbers, - sign if its a negative value and only one dot if its a float.

here is my code:

```
# org_text = gets something from clipboard

new_text = [x.strip() for x in org_text.split(',')]  # as you can see new_text is a list of strings

if len(new_text) > 1:
    text = re.compile(r'[^\d.-]+').sub('', new_text[0])
```

Later on I use the following for some adjustments:

```
text = text.lstrip(' .').rstrip('-. ')
text = text[0] + text[1:].replace('-', '')
```

It doesnt do exactly what I want plus I believe there should be an easier way. I tried playing arround with the regex part but didnt do the trick either.

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit: I didn't make some parts clear. I use the re.compile and sub which you can see from the code. I am trying to check the clipboard text which come in org_text. Then I am seperating the values inside with the comma sign. I am only accepting the regex r'[^\d.-]+' chars and deleting the rest in that original string using ''. At this point I get everything working properly except what I mentioned in my original question. I can get more than one - and . signs AND I also get them in unproper places. That's the part I am trying to fix.

Comment: Use `r'^-?\d*\.?\d+$'` as your regex for numbers

Comment: Please show an example of `org_text`.

Comment: Any text at all.. it comes from the clipboard. I editted my question to make it more clear.

Comment: The non-exponent, numeric float parse standard is this `^-?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)$`. But that's a side issue. I read your post and you have some conceptual errors. For one, after the split, you should remove all whitespace, then use this regex. If it matches, keep the value, if it doesn't, do not keep it. You can't discern what is or isn't the right location for a decimal if you have more than 1. You can't _fix_ them.

Comment: The code I gave works the way I explained. The whitespaces are removed in the code. Because I only accept the digits, dot and minus signs.. the whitespace therefor is removed. I just add the whitespace at the second part of my code "just in case". Also I don't want to control the dot sign. I want to keep the first dot then delete the rest.

Comment: `I want to keep the first dot then delete the rest` That is a problem, how do you know which one is good or bad ?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex `[^\d.-]+` is incorrect. You are trying to [negate](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) presence of digits, `.` and `-` i.e anything other than these will match.

Use this regex instead.

**Regex:** `^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$`

**Explanation:**

- `-?` ensures that negative sign is optional. Will match if present.
- `\d+` matches digits before decimal.
- `(?:\.\d+)?` optional decimal part. Will match if present.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZhUA5r/1/)**

Comment: Tried it but doesn't work for me. I'm using the re.compile and sub features to split the string with the comma seperator. Then With the list results of string I try to put the text with the filters i'm looking for. Maybe I didn't make the above clear.